# Hiding Android title bar only in landscape mode

Tags: android, landscape, titlebar

I have an activity and want to have these conditions:

- My activity has title bar in portrait mode.
- The title bar will hide when I turn the device to go to landscape mode.
- The activity should not to recreate when goes to landscape mode, by using "configChanges" in Manifest.

I know this question is asked before, but no correct answer I found.

Comment: You may hide title bar by the configChanges callback as you mentioned in landscape mode

Comment: I have used :
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
in manifest to stop recreating the activity after change screen orientation.

Comment: and I use this code to hide title bar in landscape mode:


if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
else {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

Comment: but when I use configChanges in Manifest, titlebar does not hide in landscape mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add in style.xml

```
<style name="generalnotitle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>   <!-- //this -->
</style>
```

add in manifiest file Activity ,

```
  android:theme="@style/generalnotitle">
```

To get Orientation of Device

```
 int display_mode = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;


if (display_mode == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

        getSupportActionBar().hide(); //<< this

    } else {



    }

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

[image: Portrait Mode with title bar]

Landscape mode without Title bar

[image: Lanscape mode without title bar]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but adding this code to manifest, doesn't hide titlebar and just transparent it.

Comment: till then please add this to your manifest activity  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Comment: and in your activity's above ELSE condition please paste this one  // to remove action bar and all
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Comment: just changed titlebar color to gray...
 and this last code, hide titlebar on both portrait and landscape orientations. but  portrait titlebar should not hide.

Comment: let me create a project, please wait

Comment: hI If you are looking for title bar to hide and show a/c to orientation then please find the updated code above.